# Why do ActiveRecord queries work on one array of objects, but not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Trying to understand this behavior with Rails 3:

If I do this:

`@comments_1 = @article.comments`

I can run ActiveRecord-type queries on the @comments_1, such as `@comments_1.find(1)` and get a single record/object back in return.

`=> #<Comment id: 1, body: "lorem ipsum ...">`

However, this:

`@comments_2 = Comment.all`

Doesn't accept such queries. `@comments_2.find(1)` returns:

`=> [#<Comment id: 1, body: "lorem ipsum …">, … ]:find(1)]`

(1) Why are these outputs different?

(2) How can I get the @comments_2 array to behave the same way as @comments_1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comment.all` returns an `Array` containing all comments. Whereas `@article.comments` returns a `Relation`. A `Relation` has a lot in common with an array, but is is not an array.

About Relations: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html

Comment: Thanks spickermann and @mbratch -- I suspected something like this was going on, but what was throwing me off is that `@comments_1.class` and `@comments_2.class` both returned "Array".

I guess the meat of my question, though, is: How can I get all comments back from the database as an object that I can run AR queries on?

Comment: Just `Comment.scoped` or just `Comment` depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The query methods work on `ActiveRecord`, `Relation` (from associations), etc. So when you do:

```
@article.comments
```

The result is an object (`Relation`) that you can operate on with `where` or `find`, etc.

However, when you do this:

```
Comment.all
```

Or even this

```
@article.comments.all
```

You've created a Ruby `Array` of objects. The ActiveRecord query methods are not part of the `Array` class.